Fetch ServicePrincipal's OwnedObjects using Delta SDK query with AccessToken
I'm trying to retrieve the ownedObjects of a ServicePrincipal from the Microsoft Graph API using WithUrl because I didn't see any support for $expand in the Delta SDK.
When I run this code:
var deltaResponse = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals.Delta()
    .WithUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/delta/?$select=id&$expand=ownedObjects")
    .Request()
    .GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync(
        requestConfiguration =>
        {
             requestConfiguration.Options.Add(retryHandlerOption);
             requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}")
        },      cancellationToken);

I get the following exception:
oDataError = signing key is invalid


It seems that the WithUrl function ignores any properties in its input, so I can't pass the authorization bearer token via accessToken.
I don't necessarily need to use WithUrl—I just want to execute this query as efficiently as possible.
For example, when I tried:
var deltaResponse = await deltaRequestBuilder.GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync(
                    requestConfiguration =>
                    {
                        requestConfiguration.ConfigureCommonRequestProperties(accessToken, _retryHandlerOption);
                        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select =
                            ["ownedObjects"];
                    },
                    cancellationToken);

I got:

Exception - back link not supported: ownedObjects

Does anyone have any advice or solutions for this issue?

Do you use SDK v4 or SDK v5?

First of all, thank you for your comment! But sadly no.. Expand is unsupported in ServicePrincipal's Delta GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync
